What to do after the multivariate model for compositional data?
I have a simple compositional data set (3 measurements, must add to 100%). I understand how to do an ILR transformation, then I can do a simple multivariate regression against treatments. But then what?
There is no trivial way to relate the ILR-transformed matrix back to the original measurements, as far as I know. How do I see if a given treatment ended up favoring the relative preponderance of outcome A over outcomes B and C, for example? It is that sort of statement that would be sensible to practitioners in the field, not simply stating that treatments differed from each other. Is there a way to take the multivariate result and relate it to the relative levels in the original compositional set in a way that's more rigorous than a regression and a triplot that the regression doesn't exactly describe?

You can always do simple analyses of the original data like looking at treatment-wise means or corresponding visualisations of the proportions and interpret them. ILR transformation is not mandatory and can come with problems (logratios are very sensitive to small differences between small values, which in many applications is problematic). But even if you do analyses based on ILR for purposes at inference, you can still use all you know from looking at the raw data for interpretation.
